# AWS Cognito authentication bug with JavaScript and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am trying to fix a bug in my code that whenever a user signs up to my application with the same email twice there is no validation to stop that:

Here is my onSubmit code

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);
    try {

      const newUser = await Auth.signUp({
        username: fields.email,
        password: fields.password,
      });

      setIsLoading(false);
      setNewUser(newUser);
    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)
      if (e.name === 'UsernameExistsException') {
        ///current bug if you signup already existing user, it will succeed
        setNewUser({
          username: fields.email,
          password: fields.password,
        });
        // resend code if user wants ! Add this link
        // Auth.resendSignUp(fields.email)
        setIsLoading(false);
        return
      }
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

I can handle this error but, unfortunately, if the users sign up for the first time and refresh the page before they complete the email code validation process I get exactly the same error on their second sign up attempt and will, therefore, block their signup.

How do you go around this? I read that we can try to sign in the user check their attributes and then sign them out.

Here is the error in question:

```
{code: "UsernameExistsException", name: "UsernameExistsException", message: "An account with the given email already exists."}
code: "UsernameExistsException"
message: "An account with the given email already exists."
name: "UsernameExistsException"
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a workaround that I was able to add.. any comments/enhancements would be highly appreciated.

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);


    try {

      const newUser = await Auth.signUp({
        username: fields.email,
        password: fields.password,
      });

      setIsLoading(false);
      setNewUser(newUser);
    } catch (e) {

      console.log(e)
      if (e.name === 'UsernameExistsException') {


        ///add new try to do a signup simulation
        try {
          await Auth.signIn(fields.email, fields.password);
        } catch (e) {
          if (e.name === 'UserNotConfirmedException') {
            setNewUser({
              username: fields.email,
              password: fields.password,
            });
          } else {
            alert(`This Username is already registered`)
            //this username alredy exists so we have to display error 
            // history.push("/");
          }
        }

        // resend code if user wants ! Add this link
        // Auth.resendSignUp(fields.email)
        setIsLoading(false);
        return
      }
      onError(e);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

if I try to sign in the user, I receive the necessary errors.